# Copy files and replace token in the filename?

Tags: command-line

I've been doing Project Euler for a long time. I have a project structure that makes it really easy to create a new folder for the next question and I have a couple of boilerplate golang files to get started with.

```
ProjectEuler/001/001.go
ProjectEuler/001/001_test.go
ProjectEuler/002/002.go
ProjectEuler/002/002_test.go
...
ProjectEuler/new_question_stub/xxx.go
ProjectEuler/new_question_stub/xxx_test.go
```

When I create a new question's folder, I run these commands:

```
ProjectEuler $ mkdir 003
ProjectEuler $ cd 003
ProjectEuler/003 $ cp ../new_question_stub/xxx.go 003.go
ProjectEuler/003 $ cp ../new_question_stub/xxx_test.go 003_test.go
```

I feel there should be some way to say "copy every file out of a specific directory to the current directory, but replace token xxx with 003." It doesn't have to be one command to copy and rename in one stroke. Copying them all is easy enough but how would I rename them all after they're copied?

Edit: my use case is a pretty trivial example of only two files but I'm looking for a way to do it for an arbitrary number of files.

Answer (score 0):

Okay with using a `for` loop? Like

```
for file in ../new_question_stub/*; do cp "$file" "003${file#*xxx}"; done
```

Maybe you want to define a function for this

Answer (score -1):

You can first copy all `xxx_*` files and then use `perl rename` to rename them:

```
rename "s,^xxx,"$(basename $(pwd))"," *
```